# $routingprovider no funciona angular yeoman

Tags: angularjs

El enrutamiento no me está funcionado al generar el proyecto en yeoman, no comprendo la razón.

Cundo clikeo  algùn item del menu no me redirecciona a esa parte :

home : http://localhost:9000/#!/#%2F . 
 about : http://localhost:9000/#!/#%2Fabout . 
 loguin :  http://localhost:9000/#!/#%2F .

index.html

```
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a ng-href="#/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a ng-href="#/login">Iniciar sesiòn</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

controllers :

```
loginCtrl

    'use strict';

    angular.module('apiFrontApp').controller( 'LoginCtrl' , function(){

     var vm = this;

     vm.loginForm = {

        email : '',
        password : ''
     };

   });
```

app.js

```
    'use strict';

    /**
    * @ngdoc overview
    * @name apiFrontApp
    * @description
    * # apiFrontApp
    *
    * Main module of the application.
    */
    var app = angular
    .module('apiFrontApp', [
     'ngAnimate',
     'ngAria',
     'ngCookies',
     'ngMessages',
     'ngResource',
     'ngRoute',
     'ngSanitize',
     'ngTouch',
     'satellizer'
   ]);
     app.config(function ($routeProvider, $authProvider , $locationProvider){

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
      $authProvider.loginUrl = 
      'http://localhost:8888/api-cat/api-dev/public/auth_login';
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'main'
        })
        .when('/about', {
         templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
         controller: 'AboutCtrl',
         controllerAs: 'about'
       })
       .when( '/login' ,{
         templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
         controller: 'LoginCtrl',
         controllerAs: 'login'

       })
       .otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/'
       });

    });
```

Comment: Primero, podrías dar más detalles sobre el problema? ¿Cuál es el comportamiento actual? ¿Cuál es el comportamiento esperado? Segundo, `app.js` es un script que será ejecutado en el browser. Si defines `$authProvider.loginUrl = 'http://localhost:8888/api-cat/api-dev/public/auth_login';`, el browser intentará acceder a localhost:8888 para autenticar. Tienes el servidor de autenticación ejecutándose en la misma computadora que el browser? Tercero, has considerado ui-router (http://ui-router.github.io)?

Answer (score 0):

En la versión de angular 1.6.* se agregaron un prefix a la URL, para resolver ese error en el archivo de app.js agrega la siguiente linea de la siguiente manera:

```
...     
  'ngTouch',
         'satellizer'
       ]);
 app.config(function ($routeProvider, $authProvider , $locationProvider){

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); //Esta linea de codigo

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
          $authProvider.loginUrl = 
          'http://localhost:8888/api-cat/api-dev/public/auth_login';
          $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
              templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
              controller: 'MainCtrl',
              controllerAs: 'main'
            })
...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente era eso. Pero no entendi porque se dio ese error, si pudieras explicarmelo mejor te lo agradezco.

Comment: Por defecto en la versión 1.5 venia de esta manera, con la cadena vacía, al pasar a la versión 1.6 por defecto trae .('!') por lo que a las URLs les agrega ese prefijo. Seguramente estás trabajando con Yeoman y por defecto agrega en las URLs el prefijo de # que era normal en la versión 1.5. Es por eso que te da ese error. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

en **index.html** cambia:

`<li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>`

por:

`<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>`

lo mismo en el titulo:

`<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">"Title"</a>`

todo porque **"Home"** es la clase activa y genera el problema en las otras páginas.

saludos desde Chile!!